# API for an iOS app to connect and control a GoPro Hero camera?

Tags: ios, api, gopro

I'm looking for a **GoPro Hero API** I could use for a POC swift app I'm developing to connect and control a GoPro Hero camera.

### Requirements:

- Be able to make basic camera settings configuration adjustments.
- Capturing streaming video and pictures from the GoPro to the iPhone.
- Shooting pictures.
- Importing the pictures that were shot.

Any suggestions about an API I could use?

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you provide your exact requirements.